# Azure B2C Mobile Journey

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We are looking to use mobile number as username for our users to sign in. In the Signup journey we just want to send one time password to validate if they have put the correct phone number.

Is it possible to achieve this using Azure B2C IEF?

Please note we do not need 2FA as we just want to validate once at the time of sign up if user has put the correct mobile number.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number).

"A B2C IEF Custom Policy which allows login via Phone Number (TOTP)".

Have a look at the issues viz.

"You need to use the SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa starter pack not the SocialAndLocalAccounts as per the Readme.

There is a missing:

ClaimsProviders
ClaimsProvider

in the xml.

When you run the sample, when it asks "Enter user name", you need to enter the phone number."

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. The sample says "Where you would like to login users solely on Phone Number and MFA via SMS or Phone Call. This approach is passwordless."   Please note we want user to create password and use his mobile as username. Only once at the time of signup we want to send OTP to make sure he has the same mobile number in possession .  Look forward to your comments. Thanks,